# Feature request: answered/viewed ratio badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, answers, views, ratio

I would like to propose the following badge (bronze or silver): `answered/viewed ratio`.

If the ratio `answered/viewed > 0.6`, then the badge will be granted.

Kind of like the conversion rate of an online store — how many people who visited the site made a purchase.

Rules:

1. Self-answered questions won't be granted.
2. Ratio calculated on "answered moment", that is logically, because `viewed` will be decreased in time.is
3. Author's view isn't encountered

**EDIT:** 
**1.** this badge should be granted to post ***author***

**2.** this badge indicates the question is interesting,because many people answered it immediately after viewed

**Use cases:**

**1.** 1 author view , **2** non-author views , **1** answer , 1 accepted answer

badge is not granted,because ratio is 1/2=05.
0.5<2/3

**2.** 1 author view , **3** non-author views ,**2** answers , 1 accepted answer

badge is granted to author,because ratio is 2/3.

Comment: @dmckee sorry,I have not got your assumption. It's concerned one question only,that is viewed and answered by different people.

Comment: Sounds like a free badge for each question that is answered? 3 views (including the one from the author) and 1 answer already grants this badge? Even more: when calculating when the first answer is posted, `answered` is always 1?

Comment: (And did you mean *"viewed will be __increased__ in time"*?)

Comment: author view should not be included

Comment: 2 non-author views and one answered doesn't guarantee badge(1/2=0.5 ratio),because rate should be more than 0.6

Comment: 3 non-author views and 2 answered is ok to get this badge,because 2/3~0.666(6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is needed.
This sounds like you are looking for a badge for how easy a question is to answer. Badges are meant to encourage a certain type of behaviour.

What behaviour are you trying to encourage here ?

Fastest gun in the west coupled with simple questions that can be solved by a search will throw out these badges.

If anything it should at least be in line with the

- Popular (1,000 views)
- Notable (2,500 views)
- and Famous Question (10,000 views) Badges

In any event none of the previous badges use number of answers a question gets as a quantifier so I see no reason to start now. Votes currently indicate how well the question is viewed by the community.

Answer (score 4):

This badge will be awarded for questions that are easily answered by a google link or something like that. Not sure if we should support that.

A lot of time (each question that has views but no answers) you will also hit by this error:
[image]

Comment: When calculating *on "answered moment"*, it seems to me `answered` is always 1. Hence: a badge for each answered question that had 2 visitors, plus one view from the author...?

Comment: @Ajran Ok if it is calculated only at answer time then yes, but I thought that each answer increases the answer counter with 1.

Comment: You may be right, @Roflcoptr, I'm not really grasping this feature request yet. (Even then, it would be 1 and up?)

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, I thought it would be calculated every time, even if no answers are there.

Comment: @Arjan,@Roflcoptr Guys,my apologies, feels stupid myself, I've edited proportion to answered/viewed,that I really intended to say.

Answer (score 1):

I see that I misunderstood the suggestion.

Now it represents an incentive to write a provocative title.

There is also the matter of *when* to measure the ratio. Certainly can't be at *any* time, because the first visit would qualify.

---

<s>Assuming you mean the possible condition of answered/viewed > [some value], I'm against the idea.</s>

We *don't* want people to answer questions that they don't have a *good* answer for, nor do we want people to avoid looking at questions. Unfortunately those are the incentives that your suggestion gives users of the site.

Yuk.

Comment: I mentioned that badge will be awarded to post Author

Comment: see EDIT section,please

Comment: @dmckeemy my apologies, feels stupid myself, I've edited proportion to answered/viewed,that I really intended to say